# How to make an identic layout after splash screen

Tags: android, android-layout

My splash screen is a `layer-list` drawable as background in app theme. Here is it:

*background_splash.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/dark_blue"/>

    <item android:top="100dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="top"
            android:src="@mipmap/img_logo"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

As you see, I place the logo with margin `100dp` from the top. Then I try to do the same in my fragment layout:

*fragment_start.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/bg_create_account">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/img_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the logo in the layout appears lower than logo on the splash screen. I thought, the problem is in the default margin of `Activity`. But if I set:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Nothing still happens. I always see the "jump" of logo from top to down about 10-20 dp. How can I avoid it?

EDIT: My activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT 2: I tried to pick up the distance manually and if I set `<item android:top="125dp">` (or 126dp) and leave `android:layout_marginTop="100dp"` I see no "jump". It means the difference is 25 or 26 dp, but where are they?

EDIT 3: according to answer from Bryan the issue exists only in Android 4.4(API 19) and above. To avoid it I overrode `styles.xml` in folder `values-19` with:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: can you post the screenshot of screen

Comment: you may need to remove the margin and padding from your activity_main.xml if it is present there

Comment: As per my thought In splash Screen you are hiding the `ToolBar` and again set in Fragment to `VISIBLE` that's why it look like upper and below in both the screen.

Comment: I added my activity xml and there are no padding or margin. The `ToolBar` is also not the reason. I use no `ToolBar` or `ActionBar`. Neither in theme nor in Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems drawable that you use for the splash screen does not take into account the size of the [status bar](https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars), but the `Activity` does. This is the ~25dp difference you are observing, though this height of ~25dp is not guaranteed to be the same on all devices.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you! It jumps only in Android 4.4 and above.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is in the ActionBarSize, try add this to the SplashScreen :

**Without AppCompat**

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

**With AppCompat**

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Or if you want, (although may be considered a bad practice), you can set a negative padding in the Activity Layout using data binding :

```
android:paddingTop="@{-1 * ?android:actionBarSize}"
```

Comment: The Splash Screen is a `layer-list`. It has no `android:paddingTop`. Anyways the problem is already solved